# Error Running IRB from Terminal on Mac - Can't find gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal, rubygems

When I type irb into terminal all I get is this:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem irb (>= 0.a) with executable irb (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I think it might be something to do with the gem library or version but can't figure it out. I am new to this and don't want to further mess things up, any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.0`. Then try again.

Comment: Ok I'll try that, thank you

Comment: This is what worked for me:
1) `brew install chruby`
2) `brew install ruby-install`
2) `ruby-install ruby 2.6.0`
3) In a new terminal window: `chruby 2.6.0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393939/homebrew-install-ruby-keg-only-cant-find-gem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homebrew install Ruby keg-only can't find gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393939/homebrew-install-ruby-keg-only-cant-find-gem)